# How can I easily reload Emacs lisp code as I am editing it?

Tags: emacs, elisp

As an Emacs beginner, I am working on writing a minor mode.  My current (naive) method of programming elisp consists of making a change, closing out Emacs, restarting Emacs, and observing the change.  How can I streamline this process?  Is there a command to refresh everything?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might try using <kbd>M-C-x</kbd> (`eval-defun`), which will re-evaluate the top-level form around point.  Unlike <kbd>M-x eval-buffer</kbd> or <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> (`exal-last-sexp`), this will reset variables declared with `defvar` and `defcustom` to their initial values, which might be what's tripping you up.

Answer (score 3):

Also try out `C-u C-M-x` which evaluates the definition at point and sets a breakpoint there, so you get dropped into the debugger when you hit that function.

`M-x ielm` is also very useful as a more feature-rich Lisp REPL when developing Emacs code.

Answer (score 2):

M-x eval-buffer should do it.

Comment: Eval-buffer reevaluates the code, but the minor mode's behavior does not seem to be updated, even if I turn it off and on again.  Is there a command I can use in combination with this one to reload the minor mode?

Comment: Well, I assumed that minor modes worked similar to .emacs file modifications, but I'm clearly wrong. My next guess was that the .emacs would also have to be refreshed- no dice. Guess we'll both need to wait for someone who knows what they're talking about to swing by. Sorry for the wrong attempt.

Answer (score 2):

What Sean said. In addition, I have `(eval-defun)` bound to a key, along with a test.  The development loop then becomes: 1) edit function, 2) press eval-and-test key, 3) observe results, 4) repeat.  This is *extremely* fast.

During development I write a test, bind it to `jmc-test`, then use the above key to run it on my just-edited function. I edit more, then press key again, testing it again. When the function works, I zap `jmc-test`, edit another function, and write another jmc-test function.  They're nearly always one line of code, so easy to just bang out.

```
(defun jmc-eval-and-test ()
  (interactive)
  (eval-defun nil)
  (jmc-test))
(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "<kp-enter>")  'jmc-eval-and-test)

(when t
  (defun myfunc (beer yum)
    (+ beer yum))
  (defun jmc-test () (message "out: %s" (myfunc 1 2))))
```

When editing "myfunc", if I hit keypad enter, it prints "out: 3".

Comment: why do you have the (when ...) form?  Otherwise, love this!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you're writing and how you've written it.  Toggling the mode *should* get you the new behavior.  If you're using `[define-minor-mode][1]`, you can add code in the body of the macro that keys off the mode variable:

```
(define-minor-mode my-minor-mode 
  "doc string"
  nil
  ""
  nil
  (if my-minor-mode
      (progn
         ;; do something when minor mode is on
      )
    ;; do something when minor mode is off
    )
```

But, another way to check it quickly would be to spawn a new Emacs from your existing one:

```
M-x shell-command emacs&
```

Answer (score 0):

I just define a function called ldf (short for load-file) in my .emacs file, 
like this:

(defun ldf (arg) (interactive "P") (load-file (buffer-file-name)))

As you can see, this little function looks up the filename of the current buffer and then loads the file. Whenever I need to reload the current buffer elisp file, just type "M-x ldf"